# How can I get the data accounts public key from a accountSubscribe message

Tags: rpc, jsonrpc-api, web3.js

How can I determine for which data account the **accountSubscribe** web-socket message is for if I'm subscribing to multiple data account at ones. The web-socket message doesn't seem to contain the public key of the data account the message is for.

The accountSubscribe method is documented [here](https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#accountsubscribe).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you make a subscription, the RPC responds with an id that uniquely identifies that *particular* subscription.

```
{
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "result": 23784,  // <-- Subscription id
  "id": 1,
}
```

All notifications for that particular subscription will arrive via the websocket connection carrying that id. Use this to correlate the notification to the original subscription.

```
{
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "method": "accountNotification",
  "params": {
    "result": { /* ... */ },
    "subscription": 23784  // <-- Subscription id
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe only to one account per RPC client using `accountSubscribe`. That's why there is no account key.

Comment: I am able to subscribe to multiple data accounts using the same web-socket connection when using the solana-test-validator. Is this not possible on dev/test and mainnet?

Comment: Over a websocket connection, you can subscribe to multiple accounts by iterating through them. So, yes, it's possible on devnet, testnet, mainnet.